# ImageResizer - Diskcache plugin - generate image without access URL IIS

Tags: imageresizer

Is it possible to generate the images in the DiskCache without making calls has IIS, from an executable and dll : ImageResizer.dll & ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.dll

But for use DiskCache it is necessary to indicate Virtual directory of IIS ?

```csharp
var config = new ImageResizer.Configuration.Config();
var diskCache = new DiskCache("~/diskcache)   // but i'm into the executable (console or windows) 
diskCache.Install(config);
```

This in the goal of generating the night the most called images with their sizes, without overloading the CPU by calling the urls from IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to 'warm up' the disk cache by pre-caching specific URLs? IIS adds negligible overhead; you're better off using a standard HTTP request or a tool like HttpTrack. If you want to limit CPU usage, only allow 1 request at a time.

There is no API for using DiskCache outside of an ASP.NET application in v3 or v4.

Comment: Yes that's it, that's the images are already in cache. They are called the night by a batch through a .net program that generates the URLs and makes the calls on IIS.
We have about 100,000 images in the cache.
Our images are mainly called early in the morning by CDN, which in turn recharges the images in their cache for the day.
This caching is to avoid CPU and IO load peak, which would be caused by the CDN call.
Too bad this is not possible, it would avoid overloading IIS.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Philipe, I assure you that the actual image processing is far more expensive than any HTTP request around it. No significant CPU or Disk I/O would be saved if you bypassed IIS.